# Does listsinceblock list all transactions, or only transactions my wallet is interested in?

Tags: json-rpc

Wondering if I call listsinceblock "", will I get all transactions that ever occurred on the blockchain regardless of whether my wallet was party to it, or will it only be a list of transactions relevant to my wallet (things I've sent/received/have a private key for at least one side of) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list my mined coins using RPC? And spend them?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36693/how-can-i-list-my-mined-coins-using-rpc-and-spend-them)

Comment: ... from all accounts within your own wallet, see here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list: "listtransactions" Returns up to [count] most recent transactions skipping the first [from] transactions for account [account]. If [account] not provided it'll return recent transactions from all accounts.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you posted the help file text for `listtransactions` when I asked about `listsinceblock` ?

Comment: Oops, yup, I see, I have mixed things up. The previous line on the same page refers to listsinceblock. Another link would be here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25103/listsinceblock-parameter-target-confirmations, and also here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32748/monitor-non-wallet-bitcoin-addresses-for-new-transactions/32755#32755. in general: if you set “txindex=1” in bitcoin.conf, then also foreign (non wallet addresses) can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

`listsinceblock` will only list txs your wallet is interested in i.e. transactions involving as input or as output an address A such that:

- either A is an address whose private key is known to your wallet and consequently can sign transactions that spend UTXOs of A
- or A is an address your wallet is following as watch-only i.e. does not know A's private key but A was added to the wallet using `importaddress`

`listtransactions` will also only return transactions your wallet is interested in but with different criteria. It returns `count` most recent txs of interest (as per above criteria) and you can also define to omit most recent `skip` txs and also filter by `label` (or `account` for older versions which is not deprecated).

All in all, following two should both return all txs your wallet is interested in:

```
bitcoin-cli listsinceblock <hash_of_genesis_block> 1 true
```

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" <a_number_greater_than_your_wallet_total_tx_count> 0 true
```

There is no direct way through CLI to return all txs in the blockchain afaik.

Comment: In the second case (i.e., A is imported as watch-only address in the wallet), will `listsinceblock` also show any coinbase transactions that used "A" as an output?

Comment: @Shobit I can't think of a reason why not. In that case "category" value would be "immature" or with > 100 confirmations "generate".

Comment: @ThalisK. is it true that “deposit” transactions are only the ones with “receive” as category? And how to consider receive transaction with 0 as amount? A deposit amount of 0 I think that is not a deposit

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri Also a coinbase transaction is a "deposit" (type "immature" and after 100 confirmations becomes "generate" and is spendable). A tx with amount == 0 can safely be ignored IMO.